# Can I create leader lines in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, leader-line

I have scripted labels in ArcGIS Online that display various attribute values. I have a box around the labels but also would like a leader line that points to the feature. Is this possible? I have searched all through the labeling options.

Comment: I think the short answer is no.